# Who was Head Boy/Head Girl while Snape was Headmaster?

Tags: harry-potter

Who became Head Boy/Head Girl when Snape was Headmaster of Hogwards? In a normal life, Harry and Hermione could have been but they were away hunting Horcruxes. Snape would have preferred someone from his own house but Draco Malfoy wasn't available anymore because he also did not return to school.

Who was selected as Head Boy or Head Girl? Is there any hint inside or outside of the books?

Comment: Pretty sure Draco was in school- "My son, Draco, is home for his Easter holidays. If that is Harry Potter, he will know." (DH chapter 23). That would make him a pretty good candidate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**We Don't Know. <sup>[TM](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11329/are-answers-that-state-we-dont-know-acceptable)</sup>**

The list of known Head Boys/Girls is as follows:

- Albus Dumbledore (mentioned in Deathly Hallows Chapter 18)
- Minerva McGonagall (mentioned in Wizarding World [article](https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/professor-mcgonagall))
- Tom Riddle (mentioned in Philosopher's Stone Chapter 17)
- James Potter (mentioned in Philosopher's Stone Chapter 4)
- Lily Potter (mentioned in Philosopher's Stone Chapter 4)
- Bill Weasley (mentioned in Philosopher's Stone Chapter 6)
- Percy Weasley (mentioned in Prisoner of Azkaban Chapter 1)
- Teddy Lupin (mentioned by JKR on [Twitter)](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/638778021663666176)

No mention is made of whom the Head Boy/Girl is after Percy's tenure during Harry's time.

Comment: I think that this dovetails nicely with what I think that Harry is tuned into. As he was growing up, who the  head boy/head girl was just isn't that important anymore. Who cares about that sort of thing when people are actively trying to kill, torture, and maim you?

Comment: @Ryan: Or worse... expel you!

Comment: @Ryan Also, all the Heads we find out about from Harry's POV (besides Tom Riddle who has special importance to the story) were Gryffindors... should we call [Marty](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ssnw2GA657s)?